# Extend: merge strings on a list from other lists (or variables) at the same time

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have 3 different lists and I need to merge them. It is easy when you need to extend a list with just an element or adding an inteire list. But with more lists or adding a variable in the middle, it seems impossible.

```
list1 = [ 'a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [ 'd', 'e', 'f']
list3 = ['g', 'h', 'i']
```

Adding just one list:

```
list1.extend(list3)
```

Return:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Adding two lists:

```
list1.extend((list2,list3))
```

Return two lists inside another list:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Adding two list with operator '+':

```
list1.extend((list2 + list3))
```

Returns

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

but if you need to do something like:

```
list1.extend(('test' + list2 + fetch[0] + list3 + etc, etc, etc))
```

will not works.Can't concatenate.

A temporary solution adding a loop could be:

```
for l1 in list2:
    list1.extend(l1)
for l2 in list3:
    list1.extend(l2)
```

to finally have:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Clearly a waste of lines and cycles

Is there a more efficient way to archive that without using external modules?

**EDIT: the example of simple lists is just to understand what basically I need. The real problem is adding string or number or index on a single line of '.extend'.**

**SOLVED:**

Wayne Werner drive me to the right direction to concatenate different type of elements.

```
list1 = [ 'a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [ 'd', 'e', 'f']
list3 = ['g', 'h', 'i']

for other_list in (['test'], str(1), list2[2], list2[1]):
    list1.extend(other_list)
```

Result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'test', '1', 'f', 'e']
```

Comment: Is your expected output equivalent to `list1 + list2 + list3`??

Comment: list + list works fine until you need to add str o an int.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: no. I realized (after) that the example is not what I was looking for. I've updated my question.Next time I'll ready again before sending out. I have some trouble when I need to add different type of elements on a list.

Comment: This will not work with strings having more than one character since they are also iterable. You will have to use an `isinstance` test to decide whether to extend or append

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that (newbie here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a clean way of extending a single list with `N` number of other lists, it's as simple as that:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for other_list in (some_iterable, some_other_iterable, another_iterable):
    my_list.extend(other_list)
```

I can't think of *any* more reasonable solution than that.

Comment: Yes, for now is the best solution possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `extend` for each of the lists you want to add on:

```
list1.extend(list2)
list1.extend(list3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `extend` one of the lists with the addition of the other two:

```
list1 = [ 'a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [ 'd', 'e', 'f']
list3 = ['g', 'h', 'i']

list3.extend(lis1 + list2)
```

Comment: It's a step forward, but if you try something like list1.extend(list2[1]+list3) it doesn't works.

Comment: If you change a solution that works, why would you expect it to still work?

Comment: @ScottHunter I was also going to say that

Comment: I do apologize, I've edited my question because it was not clear of what I need.